# Hello I have wirten an Discord Bot with Javascript but everytime i type in node index.js it doens`t work

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

The Code:

```
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const Client = new Discord.Client();


Client.on("message", function(message) {
        if(message.author.bot)return;

        if(message.content.startsWith("!say")){
            var text = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
            message.delete();
            if(!text) return message.channel.send("Du hast keine Nachricht eingegeben")
            let ambit = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("ASSUME Gaming")
            .setDescription(text)
            .setColor("RED")
            .setImage(`https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/726775608721408070/727638443831591012/JPEG_20200628_201300.jpg`)
            message.channel.send(ambit)
            
        } else

        if(message.content === "!clear") {
            message.delete();
            message.channel.bulkDelete(100).then(() => message.channel.send("Nachrichten gelöscht"))
        } else

        if(message.content === "!counter") {
            message.channel.send(`\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
        } else

        if(message.content === "!player") {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Player für ASSUME Gaming:")
            .setColor("RED")
            .addField("Fortnite Professionell", "")
            .addField("Fortnite Academy", "")
            .addField("Valorant Professionell", "")
            .addField("Valorant Academy", "")
            message.channel.send(embed)
        }

})

Client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("ich bin jetzt online!")
    Client.user.setActivity("ASSUME Gaming", {type: "PLAYING"})
    
});

Client.login("(token)")
```

The error message when i type in the Terminal "node index.js" to start the Bot:

```
(node:6808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at Client.login (C:\Users\49173\Documents\Assume Gaming\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:204:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\49173\Documents\Assume Gaming\index.js:49:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(node:6808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6808) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The color when typing node in the Terminal is also not yellow, only grey like the other things. I know that there is standing "invalid Token" but i have an valid Token from the Discord Developer Portal. Does anyone know what could be the reason?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you have an invalid token, that is the error so that's what it is. Perhaps you copied the *Client Secret* or *ID* and not the *Bot User Token* from the developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

Your token is incorrect. Make sure you're getting the right token from [here](https://discord.com/developers).

In the unlikely case that `"(token)"` is the actual token you're trying to use, you need to use the token from the link above and not just simply "(token)"`.